# Python cx_Freeze Exe Blogger API authentification issue - blogger.dat and secrets in root directory but posting doesnt work - no errors

Tags: python, api, exe, blogger

I just created a python executable with cx_freeze, there are multiple blog API's like tumblr and all in all it worked out well.

But Google's Blogger API doesnt work. I get the secrets from ouath2 and put them into the directory. Then I start my .exe file and want to work with a google blog, it redirects me to an URL where it asks me to accept access on my blogger data. Until now everything is okay, now it should create a blogger.dat file in the directory with expire token etc.

But it doesnt do anything, it tells me authentification succesfull but doesnt create the blogger.dat file. If you manualy put it in there. it recognizes it, because there is no redirect, but it doesnt post my content and no errors aswell.

thats the directory which I created with cx_Freeze: no blogger.dat is created there even if the authentification is succesfull, putting it in there manualy make google recognize it, but i cannot post
http://puu.sh/k2VK1/109e3cd348.png

Thats the class that I use for authetification: I also tryed to replace **doc** with "blogger.dat"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from oauth2client import client
from googleapiclient import sample_tools

# Authenticate and construct service.
def google_blogger_zugangsdaten():

    global service
    service, flags = sample_tools.init(
    sys.argv, 'blogger', 'v3', __doc__ , "client_secrets.json",
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger')


def google_blogger_execute(google_blogname, bild_uri_zum_posten, alt_attribut_bild, title_attribut_bild, google_post_title, google_post_content):

    blogs = service.blogs()
    thisusersblogs = blogs.listByUser(userId='self').execute()
    for blog in thisusersblogs['items']:
        print('The blog named \'%s\' is at: %s id is: %s' % (blog['name'], blog['url'], blog['id']))

    posts = service.posts()

    #blog_id = 0
    #google_blogname = "Development Blog"
    for blog in thisusersblogs['items']:
        if blog['name'] == google_blogname:
            #blog_id = blog['id']

            request = posts.insert(blogId=blog['id'], body = {"title" : google_post_title, "content" :  "<img src='" + bild_uri_zum_posten + "' title='" + title_attribut_bild + "' alt='" + alt_attribut_bild + "'><br>" + google_post_content})
            request.execute()
```

Thank you all, my first post here, usualy I only find solutions here. Hope I dont missed something

Comment: I am facing the same issue..However I can share the trace back with at least. httplib2.ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at accounts.google.com    .....If you found a solution already, do share